# Twitter message post in Titanium

Tags: twitter, titanium, message, tweets

I got some code by doing search which is doing a lot for me in showing the my tweets in tableview,till now fine. I want to add one more functionality to it that user can post the message from the sameapp.

So I just modified the code as per. While I hit the request I got result status as successful but message is not posting to my wall. I have all keys and getting access token as well.

```
 var client = Twitter({
      consumerKey: "have Key ",
      consumerSecret: "have Key",
      accessTokenKey: accessTokenKey, 
      accessTokenSecret: accessTokenSecret
    });


client.request("1/statuses/update.json", {status:'TEST'}, 'GET', function(e) {
              if (e.success) {alert(e.success);

          } else  {
            alert(e.error);
          }
```

**Updated:** I have go through the Twitter Dev API
This is the URL http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.format with required parameter "status". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @ymn, I have to share messages and pictures from my mobile app, being build using Titanium mobile. Would you please guide me in this regard. How did you accomplished this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending GET request to update status whereas twitter api needs it to be a POST request.

Try something like

```
client.request( "1/statuses/update.json", {status:'TEST'}, 'POST', function(e) {
          if (e.success)
          {
             alert(e.success);
          } else  {
             alert(e.error);
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this application: https://github.com/appcelerator-titans/tweetanium

From what I understand this is a fully working example of a twitter app created using Titanium Mobile.  Perhaps you can follow the logic in here and see where you need to adjust.